# TYPO3 f:link.action routing is wrong

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

I have the following link action:

```
<f:link.action controller="FrontendVideo"
               action="listSelectedPublic"
               arguments="{breadcrumb : currBreadcrumb.sortCode}">
    <p class="breadcrumb-custom-text" id="noFive">
        {currBreadcrumb.name}
    </p>
</f:link.action>
```

Link is rendered, but the link behind is wrong. 
Always the whole url is concat to the URL

Example

`url.de/view/` and the the whole is added `url.de/view/?tx_institutsvideoverwaltung_videoverwaltungfrontend[action]=listSelectedMember&tx_institutsvideoverwaltung_videoverwaltungfrontend[controller]=FrontendVideo`

Result is:

`url.de/view/url.de/view/?tx_institutsvideoverwaltung_videoverwaltungfrontend[action]=listSelectedMember&tx_institutsvideoverwaltung_videoverwaltungfrontend[controller]=FrontendVideo`

Problem is present since migration from TYPO3 6.2.31 to 7.6.23

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with "the whole URL is concat to the URL"? The query parameters are expected to be there. What is the actual URL you're having rendered in your HTML output?

Comment: updated the question above with an example. the wohle url is addad at the end. `url.de/view/`+ `url.de/view/......`

Comment: Is that what you see when you click the link, or is this really what you are having rendered in your HTML source code? Are you using `config.baseUrl`  or `config.absRefPrefix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TYPO3 configuration either `config.baseUrl` or `config.absRefPrefix` (preferred one) is missing.

In `config.baseUrl` you set your domain, in `config.absRefPrefix` you set the base folder of your installation related to the DocRoot, normally only `/`